# Redirecting calls to different web applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes, httpmodule

I have the following scenario to implement:

- User requests `/HR/Employee/Get` on the main website (`localhost:80`)
- `HR` is the name of an application hosted in IIS on a different port (say `localhost:8081`), or it could be deployed on another server on the network.
- The URL is intercepted and mapped to `https://localhost:8081/HR/Employee/Get` (I managed to get this working)
- Now I need to transfer/redirect the call to the target URL, and then return the result back to the client (browser in this case).

I tried to use `Server.TransferRequest` but it only works if I'm transfering to a route within the same domain. Is there any way I could make this work without having to issue another HTTP request to the target URL? I simply want the site on port 80 to act like a reverse proxy or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think Server.Transfer(Request) is only meant for redirecting within your web application, so I guess you'll have to use Response.Redirect to redirect to external pages.

Comment: @Hanno: exactly. `Server.Transfer`, `Context.RewritePath` are allowed to rewrite paths withing the same web application only.

Comment: @Alex and Hanno, yes you two are correct, which is why I've asked this question in the first place. Is there any way I could over-come this limitation?

Comment: @Kassem: don't think so. The only way to do this I know is to use `Response.Redirect`. But I'd like to be wrong ;)

Comment: Or if you can use the IIS rewrite module then you could get it to work by setting up a rule in your `web.config`. Is that an option?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I tried that, it did not work for me, and I would prefer to do things without having to configure IIS. Currently, I'm trying to use `HttpModule` and an `HttpHandler`; apparently there's no way out of issuing a new Http request.

Comment: Because I know you can do a rewrite to a different domain using the rewrite module and [ARR module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing). But I have no idea if in your case it can help.

Answer (score 0):

try RedirectPermanent, this will do a [301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

```
public ActionResult Get()
{
  return RedirectPermanent("https://localhost:8081/HR/Employee/Get");
}
```

you can also use 
 RedirectToActionPermanent and
 RedirectToRoutePermanent